# AngularJS - copy JSON text to textarea in new window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service which calls for a JSON response, I would like to copy this JSON response to a textarea in a new window. Is there a way to do this in AngularJS?

What I have so far:

```
GetData.getJson(item).then(function(returnValues){
    var data = returnValues[0].data; // a json object as a string, ideally I would like to pretty print this in the new window.

    // need to create text area in the new window so I can paste the text in
    $window.open("data:text/html,"+ encodeURIComponent(data), "_blank", "width=800,height=600");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that Angular can do this quite easily, I just wasn't too familiar with opening new windows.

```
GetData.getJson(productNumber).then(function(returnValues){
    var data = JSON.stringify(returnValues[0].data, null, 4); // pretty print
    data = "<textarea cols='100' rows='150'>" + data + "</textarea>"; // encase in text area
    $window.open("data:text/html,"+ encodeURIComponent(data), "_blank", "width=800,height=600");
});
```